# I have a question about the paramether of GetPriorityClass Function (and [in] attribute)

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, win32-process

```
DWORD GetPriorityClass(
  [in] HANDLE hProcess
);
```

In the documentation they says if the function succeeds, the return value is the priority class of the specified process.

The parameter takes `[in] HANDLE hProcess`  that will be the process that i will be take the priority, but i dont know what means `[in]` or if i have to put some data into the parameter.

---

The docs says the next thing :

`[in] hProcess`

A handle to the process.

---

But doesnt explain or show some example or how can i fill the param.

Comment: `[in]` means that the argument is an ***in**put* argument. Nothing more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-getpriorityclass), `GetPriorityClass`:

> Retrieves the priority class for the **specified process**.

*(emphasis is mine)*

The handle to the process is passed as the `hProcess` **input** argument (marked with the `[in]` attribute) to the function.
This just means you have to supply it yourself.

**Something like:**

```
HANDLE hMyProcess = ...;
DWORD dwRes = GetPriorityClass(hMyProcess);
if (dwRes == 0)
{
    // Handle error
}
else
{
    // Use the priority class in dwRes
}
```

**Notes:**

- More info about `[in]` attribute here: [SAL documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/code-quality/understanding-sal?view=msvc-170) and here: [IDL documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/midl/in). SAL is Microsoft's source-code annotation language which uses the `_In_` style for this attribute. IDL is the interface definition language which uses the `[in]` style. But the idea is the same. BTW the current Windows SDK headers use the SAL style.
- A complete example showing the usage of `GetPriorityClass` (among other functions): [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/toolhelp/taking-a-snapshot-and-viewing-processes.).

Comment: Although it's the same idea and Microsoft comes from a long way in this matter, [in] is not strictly related here to IDL, but to  source-code annotation language (SAL) : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/code-quality/understanding-sal

Comment: @SimonMourier thanks for the info. But isn't this specific format with `[]` according to IDL "style" ? I see that the SAL version uses `_In_`. Anyway since the idea is the same I thought that the IDL documentation is proper for getting more info on the issue.

Comment: Look at a recent processthreadsapi.h header, you'll see it uses SAL. Documentation format is different for some (legacy) reason.

Comment: @SimonMourier I looked at the latest processthreadsapi.h header and you are indeed right. Edited my answer to add info about SAL.

Comment: There are at least 3 different versions of SAL, none used []. v0 was just uppercase like IN. Win8 WDK switched from v1 to v2.